# Appending data to stream when using BufferedMediaTypeFormatter

Tags: c#, pdf, asp.net-web-api, stream

I've created a media type formatter (BufferedMediaTypeFormatter) that serializes my to-do-list to PDF when calling the API and specifying content-type: application/pdf.

Now I'm struggling with merging an existing PDF to this dynamically generated PDF in the WriteToStream method. I tried writing the writeStream to a file (for debugging purposes) at the end of the method, but the resulting file only contains 24 bytes as opposed to the 464165 bytes returned from the Web API. It seems the writeStream is written to after the WriteToStream method.

Using the code below will result in the Web API returning a valid PDF with a size of 464165 bytes while the Out.pdf is invalid with a size of 24 bytes. Any ideas on what I'm doing wrong?

```
public override void WriteToStream(Type type, object value, Stream writeStream, HttpContent content)
{
    using (var writer = new StreamWriter(writeStream))
    {
        // Removed code writing to writeStream for clarity.

        using (var anotherWriter = new StreamWriter(@"C:\Temp\Out.pdf"))
        {
            anotherWriter.Write(writeStream);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Try flushing the writer and also I would use the regular media type formatter i.e MediaTypeFormatter, so that i can do this async...note that stream writer has async methods too...

Comment: I tried flushing the writer (writeStream) before writing to anotherWriter, but it doesn't help.